# change header for a data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Python Pandas Dataframe:

```
        Coode       detial        quantity     unit  Unnamed: 13    Crost       Sum
0   Barnch1     NaN           NaN       NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN
1   food        NaN           NaN       NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN
2   111100016   Vanilla           243       กรัม             NaN    0       0
3   111100030   Chocolate         2000      กรัม     NaN    0       0
4   111100031   Strawberry        2000      กรัม     NaN    0       0       
5   Barnch2     NaN           NaN       NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN
6   meat        NaN           NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
7   105000003   Sliced ​​Beef     2260      กรัม         NaN    0       0
8   105000009   Sliced ​​Pork Neck  1400        กรัม         NaN    0       0
9   111100030   Sliced Pork Loin  2000      กรัม         NaN    0       0
```

I am looking for the most simple way to get:

```
0   Barnch   type   Coode         detial    quantity    unit    NaN Crost   Sum
1   Barnch1 food    111100016     Vanilla        243    กรัม    NaN 0   0
2   Barnch1 food    111100030   Chocolate       2000    กรัม    NaN 0   0
3   Barnch1 food    111100031   Strawberry      2000    กรัม    NaN 0   0
4   Barnch2 meat    105000003   Sliced ​​Beef       2260    กรัม    NaN 0   0
5   Barnch2 meat    105000009 Sliced ​​Pork Neck  1400  กรัม    NaN 0   0
6   Barnch2 meat    111100030  Sliced Pork Loin 2000    กรัม    NaN 0   0
```

Comment: Your input is unclear and too messed up, how did you generate the dataframe in the first place? There is likely some work to do there before, at least to avoid the Unnamed columns. Please clarify, else you'll just have a clunky solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#test non missing values
m = df['detial'].notna()

#for each consecutive NaNs add counter for possible test first and second NaNs
s = df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum()).cumcount().reindex(df.index, fill_value=-1)

#insert new columns with replace non first and not second value in s to missing values
 #forward filling missing values in both
df.insert(0,'Barnch', df['Coode'].where(s.eq(0)).ffill())
df.insert(1,'type', df['Coode'].where(s.eq(1)).ffill())

#remove only NaNs columns and rows with NaNs in detial
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').dropna(subset=['detial'])
```